# Compare bounded (unbounded) derived categories of D-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

I am reading [HTT, D-modules, Perverse Sheaf and Representation Theory]. In [HTT, 1.5.7, page 32], it is claimed that an equivalence of categories between bounded derived category with quasi-coherent cohomologies and bounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves of $D_X$ modules
$$D_{qc}^b(\mathrm{Mod}(D_X))\sim D^b(\mathrm{Mod}_{qc}(D_X)).$$
It says that "It will not be used in what then follows and the proof is omitted." The refference it cited is [Borel, Algebraic D-modules VI.2.10. page 222], whose proof is really short (almost 1 page). However, it seems there are some problems.

Firstly, some notations do not make sense. In [Borel], $\mathcal{A}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras (Not necessarily be commutative. In our case, $D_X$ is non-commutative). Let us assume $X$ is a "good" scheme. It is denoted by $\mu (\mathcal{A})$ the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{A}$-modules, where quasi-coherent means quasi-coherent over $\mathcal{O}_X$. Our goal is to prove the fully faithfulness
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{D(\mu (A))}(F^\cdot, G^\cdot)=\mathrm{Hom}_{D_{qc}(\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{A}))}(F^\cdot, G^\cdot),~F^\cdot,G^\cdot\in D^b(\mu (\mathcal{A})),$$
In the second set $\mathrm{Hom}_{D_{qc}(\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{A}))}(F^\cdot, G^\cdot)$ a morphism is represented by a third complex $H^\cdot$ which may not in $\mu(\mathcal{A})$, and a quasi-isomorphism. In [Borel], the following notation of $\mathrm{Hom}^\cdot$-complex seems uncorrect
$$\mathrm{Hom}^\cdot_{D(\mu (A))}(F^\cdot, G^\cdot) .$$
I will assume that this is a typo in the following.

Secondly, I do not understand how it was able to reduce to the affine case in [Borel]. I do know the adjointness of pushforward and pullback
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(F^\cdot,i^*(\tilde{J}))=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}|_U}(F^\cdot|_U,\tilde{J}).$$
But I am not sure if the following is true
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A})}(F^\cdot,i^*(\tilde{J}))=\mathrm{Hom}_{D(\mathcal{A}|_U)}(F^\cdot|_U,\tilde{J})$$

Thirdly, I have another possible explanation using $\mathrm{Hom}^\cdot$-complex and $R\mathrm{Hom}$ by using an injective resolution of $G^\cdot$ in $K^+(\mathrm{Mod}_{qc}(\mathcal{A})))$, say $I^\cdot \in \mathrm{Ob}(K^+(\mathrm{Mod}_{qc}(\mathcal{A})))$. Then
$$H^0R\mathrm{Hom}_{\mu(\mathcal{A})}(F^\cdot,G^\cdot)=H^0\mathrm{Hom}^{\cdot}_{\mu(\mathcal{A})}(F^\cdot,I^\cdot)\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^+(\mu(\mathcal{A}))}(F^\cdot,G^\cdot)$$
This approach finally suffers from I do not know if an injective object in $\mu(\mathcal{A})$ is injective in $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{A})$. In [HTT, 1.4.14, page 29] it was particularly added a comment "We do not claim that $I$ is injective in $\mathrm{Mod}(D_X)$". In [Thomason and Trobaugh, Higher Algebraic K-theory of schemes and of derived categories, Appendix B.4, page 410], it is explained that in a general scheme, the right derived funtor in $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ and the right derived funtor in $\mathrm{Mod}_{qc}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ could have different effects on quasi-coherent objects [SGA 6, II App. I 0.2]. While in Noetherian case, they are the same, essentially because the injective objects in $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ are also injective in $\mathrm{Mod}_{qc}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ on a Noetherian scheme [Hartshorne, Residues and Duality, 7.18, 7.19, page 133].

I noticed that in [Bökstedt-Neeman, Homotopy limits in triangulated categories, corollary 5.5], it is true for a quasi-compact and separated scheme that the natrual inclusion 
$$D(\mathrm{QCoh}(\mathcal{O}_X)) \to D_{qc}(\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X))$$
is an equivalence of category
But their proof is pretty long and I am not familiar with them. I do not know what is essential so far and whether it extends to our case for D-modules. 
Also see [Stacks project, 36.3] for the affine case, whose proof is not so short. These kind of results are unbounded.

Bernstein himself in his notes [Bernstein, Algebraic theory of D-moduls, page 14, lemma] claimed a similar without proof. He simply said "properties of coherent D-modules imply the natural morphism
$$D_{coh}(\mathrm{Mod}(D_X))\to D(\mathrm{Mod}_{coh}(D_X))$$
is an equivalence of categories". But it seems [Bökstedt-Neeman]'s long argument implies that this should not be simple.
I am a beginner, so I am not sure if this question is important. However,  it seems that we could restrict ourselves in just one of them safely and put this question aside. Bernstein himself in his notes [Bernstein, Algebraic theory of D-moduls, page 22, remark] said that "I do not know whether the natural morphism $D(Hol(D_X))\to D_{hol}(D_X)$ is an equivalence of categories. In a sense, I do not care."

Comment: I guess one can adapt the proof from Stacks Project in this situation. The key is to construct functors in both direction. The functor $D(qc-D_X) \to D_{qc}(D_X)$ is just the natural ``inclusion''. To construct the functor in the other direction, one considers the inclusion $qc-D_X-Mod \to D_X-Mod$, this admits a right adjoint $D_X-Mod \to qc-D_X-Mod$by the result analogous to Tag 077P.  Then its derived functor gives a map $D(D_X) \to D(qc-D_X)$ its restriction to $D_{qc}(D_X)$ is called $RQ$. These two functors are adjoint by definition, so one only needs to check that ...

Comment: that the unit and counit maps are isomorphism. But in order to check this, we can forget about $D_X$-mod structure (one needs to check that $RQ$ is compatible with the functor $RQ: D_{qc}(\mathcal{O}_X) \to D(qc-\mathcal{O}_X)$) and work with just $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Then in the affine case, this can be done directly using that $RQ_X=\widetilde{R\Gamma(X, -)}$ and the case of a general sep'd quasi-compact scheme can be reduced to the affine case by means of Tag 09T6.

Comment: Dear @gdb, I wanted to express my appreciation for the strategy you outlined, which can be found in Thm. A.0.3 of my draft at https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~haohao.liu/DFM.pdf. I found your approach to be insightful and valuable for my writing. I hope my comment is not offensive in any way, and I kindly ask you to let me know if you have any concerns. Thank you for your time and expertise.